# How to change language of LABEL_DETECTION results?

Tags: label, detection, google-cloud-vision

Previously I was trying to extract text in Portuguese from an image, and realized that the results came out missing some special marks over some letters.

Even the documentation saying that languages based on Latin, in this case Portuguese, doesn`t require languageHints to be set up, I decided to add pt-BR and it worked perfectly.

Now I would like to get the results of LABEL_DETECTION in a different language because it comes always in English, even with my own languageHints preferences. To do this, for now I am just translating the results. It doesn't seem to be efficient so I was thinking about something easier than that, in case Cloud Vision supports it.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

Vision.Builder builder = new Vision.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
builder.setVisionRequestInitializer(new
    VisionRequestInitializer(CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY));
Vision vision = builder.build();

BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchAnnotateImagesRequest =
    new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
batchAnnotateImagesRequest.setRequests(new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>() {{
AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();

// Add the image
Image base64EncodedImage = new Image();
// Convert the bitmap to a JPEG
// Just in case it's a format that Android understands but Cloud Vision
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

// Base64 encode the JPEG
base64EncodedImage.encodeContent(imageBytes);
annotateImageRequest.setImage(base64EncodedImage);


//this part I thought would be enough to get LABEL_DETECTION results in Portuguese, but it's not.
ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext();
String [] languages = { "pt-BR" };
imageContext.setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList(languages));
annotateImageRequest.setImageContext(imageContext);


// add the features we want
annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(array);

// Add the list of one thing to the request
add(annotateImageRequest);}});

Vision.Images.Annotate annotateRequest =
    vision.images().annotate(batchAnnotateImagesRequest);
// Due to a bug: requests to Vision API containing large images fail when GZipped.
annotateRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
Log.d(TAG, "created Cloud Vision request object, sending request");
BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();

//function to get Strings from response
photoDescriptor.callTextAdaptation(response);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code. It's hard to diagnose what you're doing wrong without it.

Comment: I'm having difficulties translating labels as well. I'm using the REST API and I'm not entirely sure if it can be done with that, since I can't find any documentation on it. The OCR Language Support docs however has a list of supported languages it uses: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages As you can see it supports different types of Chinese ("zh-CN" & "zh-TW") but no no different types of Portuguese for Brazil / Portugal. I'm not an Android developer so I can't say your code works at all, but I would try to use "pt" instead of "pt-BR" as a language string.